# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, possibly something about a byte string error?

Tags: python, tkinter, encryption, password-encryption

What I am trying to do is, make an encryption program, that user inputs file name, and the key size, and that creates a key size accordingly. I use the `os.urandom(e2.get())` for this, its normally used like `os.urandom(5)` for example, but I guess I should be able to use it as well. But it gives me error around here:

```
os.urandom(e2.get()) TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This looks easy right? No. It's not really an `int`, its something random like this: `b'\xe4\xa2\x8bho\x96FE\xb3\xd7\xe8\xd1\x98\xc2\xd32'`

```
import string
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import base64
import os
import bottom as bottom
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


def createKey():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    print(key)
    file = open('key.key', 'wb')
    file.write(key)
    file.close()
    password_provided = "password"
    password = password_provided.encode()    
    salt = os.urandom(e2.get())
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
    print(key)
def encryptFile():
    file = open('key.key', 'rb')
    key = file.read()
    file.close()
    print("File name: %s" % (e1.get()))

    str1 = e1.get()
    str2 = '.encrpyted'
    str3 = str1 + str2
    print("After encryption: %s" % (str3))
    with open(e1.get(), 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    fernet = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)
    with open(str3, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(encrypted)
master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master,
         text="Choose").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master,
         text="key Size").grid(row=1)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(master,
          text='Create key',
          command=createKey).grid(row=3,
                                       column=0,
                                       sticky=tk.W,
                                       pady=4)
tk.Button(master,
          text='Encrpyt', command=encryptFile).grid(row=3,
                                                    column=1,
                                                    sticky=tk.W,
                                                    pady=4)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is not much mystery in this error. `e2.get()` returns a string but [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) expects an integer argument.

Comment: It's not an integer actually. It's a byte string I guess. And I tried to change it to string, it still gives me error.

Comment: @Stayheuh in that case, please update the code in the question to show how you overcame that trivial issue..  and include the input you put in the Entry field that generates the error you are getting.

Comment: The `5` in `os.urandom(5)` is the number of random bytes that you request from the system. If you convert `b'\xe4\xa2\x8bho\x96FE\xb3\xd7\xe8\xd1\x98\xc2\xd32'` to int and pass that instead of `5` to `os.random` then you will get an error because you cannot request that many bytes of random data. No system in the universe has that much memory. You should think about what you want to do.

Comment: OOHH wait. Now I understand. e2.get is string by default. It's not int. I did int(e2.get()) now its okay.

Comment: If it is solved, you can create your own answer and accept it as the answer.

Comment: I can't add codes into my comments its very complicated, it doesn't take it as code.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: e2.get method was taking a string, but os.urandom doesn't accept string. So what I did was:

```
b=int(e2.get())
a = (os.urandom(b))
print(a)
salt = a
```